# POST http://localhost:3000/filePath 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, axios

Getting 404 not found when I try to do the following

> Ecommerce.js

```
return (
    <div className="mt-24">
      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
        <div className="w-400 bg-white dark:text-gray-200 dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg rounded-2xl p-6 m-3">
          <div className="mt-10">
            <div className="mt-8">
              <FileUpload/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

This request is called in `<FileUpload/>`

```
const uploadFiles = (file) => {
  //
  if (!file) return;
  if (!initialData) return null;
  const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`);
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {
      const prog = Math.round(
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      );
      setProgress(prog);
    },
    (error) => console.log(error),
    () => {
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async () => {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/filePath', {
          'path': file.name
        }).then(() => console.log(file.name));
        update();
      });
    }
  );
};
```

I only started getting this error when I tried to integrate my work with another frontend template project. On my project with a simple basic template it works fine.

I'm thinking the error is somehow in relation to the project structure.. I'm not sure though.

I'll show the import

> Ecommerce.js

```
import FileUpload from '../FileUpload/FileUpload';
```

**EDIT: Flask API**

```
# File download Link
@app.route('/filePath', methods=['POST'])
def get_path():
    data = request.get_json()["path"]
    storage.child(f"files/{data}").download(f"files/Resume.pdf")
    return "Success.."
```

**2nd EDIT**

So, I remembered that in my original project I did this in

> package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Now it's giving me this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/insert' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
> 'http://localhost:5000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Comment: The server is telling you that `/filePath` doesn't exist on the server (or at least doesn't handle POST requests).  Do you have any information indicating otherwise?  Why do you expect it to handle this request?

Comment: Honestly, because on my simple template project it does. The path /filePath is from a Flask api that has nothing to do with reactjs or node so I'm confused why this is happening. I'll show the flask code in an edit

Comment: Is this Flask API running on port 3000, or is something else running on port 3000?  You mentioned Node, are you also running a NodeJS server on that port instead?

Comment: I have 2 servers. NodeJS server runs on port 8080 and Flask api runs on port 5000. Here I'm posting from ReactJs to the Flask api basically. The ReactJs dev server runs on 3000

Comment: Well, this code is looking for a server on port 3000.  Maybe this is just a typo?

Comment: Why does it work on my other project just as it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246794/discussion-between-moudhaffer-bouallegui-and-david).

Comment: I certainly can't speak to your "other project", but if a request to `http://localhost:3000/filePath` works then presumably a server is listenting on that port and successfully responding to that request.  But, given the information present so far, the server listening on that port does not handle that route.  You can change the ports your servers run on.  You may encounter a CORS problem when trying to make an AJAX request to one port from a page that was served from another port.

Comment: @David I got this error instead now, I updated the question

Comment: Yup, that's the CORS error you could encounter.  Your options in that case are either to enable CORS requests on your Flask server (I wouldn't know how to do that, I have no Flask knowledge) or to serve the page from the same port at your Flask server (again, no knowledge of that).  Overall it sounds like what you have are questions about Flask, not about ReactJS or Axios.